# Solving this second order ODE ($y" + y^{-1} =1$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the following type of differential equation while solving a configuration in physics (specifically - viscous fluids)
$$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac {1}{y} = 1$$
Where $y = f(x)$

The physics problem is not relevant here,
I put my question here to ask if there is a nice solution to this. I don't have much formal knowledge of solving a second order D.E. and after some attempts, couldn't get anywhere.

Any help (either to solve this, or to convince me that there is no elementary solution) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This says WA:$$\text{Solve}\left[\int _1^{y(x)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1+2
   (K[1]-\log
   (K[1]))}}dK[1]{}^2=(c_2+x){}^2,y(x)\right]$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer, it's just not nice. Multiply both sides by $y'$:

$$y'y'' +\frac{y'}{y} = y' \implies \frac{1}{2}(y')^2 + \log y = y + C_1$$

$$\sqrt{2}x + C_2 = \pm\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y - \log y +C_1 }}dy$$

for the nonconstant solution and choosing a definite sign for the derivative. We can do this without ambiguity because $y'$ from the equation above can never be $0$ ($\log y < y$) for positive choices of constant $C_1$. For negative choices I would imagine that there are oscillatory solutions.

However there is a constant solution we lost by multiplying both sides by $y'$ in the very beginning. That solution is $y=1$.

Comment: You should have another constant of integration:  $$\frac{1}{2}(y')^2+\ln(y)=y+k\,.$$

Comment: @Batominovski thanks will fix.

Comment: I see, ... Wolfram Alpha does not have anything for that integral either. Thanks!